# SP2013 - Site templates and design package's heritance

Tags: solution-package, sub-site, inheritance, design-manager

I have a blocking issue on SP 2013 (yes, I know we are now on the edge of SP2016, but that was a customer's choice...)

**What do we want :**

We would like to create 3 site templates (using team site, project site and another team site, all of them with several settings.)

And we would like our custom appearance to be deployed on every sub-site even the sites created with site templates.

**What do we do :**

1. Create a site collection with the higher site having the good
   settings.
2. Create a site template from this site collection
3. Activate the Site Collection feature "SharePoint Server Publishing
   Infrastructure" to be able to import an extern design package
4. Precisions : the design package contains style library's css/js/img/fonts folders, custom master pages, and composed looks. The customer wants to be able to choose between 3 masterpages and 6 colors for each, so we created composed to be quicker to choose.
5. Import and apply the design package (In Solutions, the design
   package is activated)
6. Create a subsite of this site collection
   using the site template created in step 2.

**What is happening :**

The subsite is well created and the content is good and well placed.
BUT the design package do not apply.
And if i go to "Change the Look", only the standard looks appear, and not my custom ones.
I know that you can herit the **master page** from the parent by going to Site settings > Aspect > Master page and then choose "herit from the parent site's master page", but this is not what we want. We want the subsite to **herit the design package** (with every master page, spcolor, spfont, composed look etc...) from the parent site. Because we have several possible masterpages and composed looks in it and we want the customer to be able to chose between them.

**So, can you help me on how to herit the design package from the parent ?**

Thanks a lot for your effort and time !

Have a nice day ;)

Answer (score 0):

Did you already spot the **Theme**-options available at **Site Master Page Settings**? I'd say having this option activated in the site template should automatically apply the parent design package.

Have a look at the following image:

[image]

Comment: thanks, but yes, this is what i'm talking about when i say "I know that you can herit the master page from the parent by going to Site settings > Aspect > Master page and then choose "herit from the parent site's master page" ".
But we do not want to inherit **ONLY** the parent master page, but  the **WHOLE** masterpages which are present in parent site. Do you know how to do that ?

Comment: @Gaelle I think you are mixing up some terminology here. There is always one master page in use, the others are available if they just have been published. Masterpages (in plural) are not "inherited". Also the setting I'm pointing out in my answer (the one highlighted with green) is to inherit the **design package**, not the masterpage. So to make it clear: If you wish to inherit the *design package*, activate the `Inherit the theme from the parent of this site`. If you (also) wish to inherit the *masterpage*, activate the masterpage-related inherit-settings as well.

Comment: thanks for the precision, i'll try it a little later and come back with some news.